# Azure AD B2C 'newUser' and 'auth_time' claims lifetime

Tags: azure, jwt, azure-ad-b2c

How long is the newUser and auth_time claims populated (or set to 'true') for?

I'm finding that after initial token expiration (60 minutes from registration) on renewal of session via a refresh token I am still seeing 'newUser' being populated and set to true. I notice on older tokens that the auth_time claim is no longer present either.

It's not documented anywhere the behaviour of these claim so I'd love to know the details so I can reliably use them in logic that checks for them.

Comment: Based on other discussions it seems to be that until the initial refresh token expires then these values will be set, though I have not validated that as yet.

Comment: Are you using built-in policies or custom policies?

Comment: This was with built-in policies.